# What counts as a bag and what counts as a vest?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, clothing

Say you get a [Hydration vest](http://www.uscav.com/condor-mesh-hydration-vest/) where the entire back of the vest is a gigantic pocket. Or even worse, a  [Technical Vest](http://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/78256?page=technical-upland-vest-pack). Is this a bag? Where does a bag start and where does clothing stop?

The question is travel related: I am wondering about this for carry on.

Comment: Do you mean in general fashion terms, or for travelling on a plane, or what?

Comment: Your second example is named explicitly as a "pack" and listed under "gear" not clothing, so it is a "bag" in terms of airline carry on.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question. I can guess at what you're hinting at, but so far this doesn't appear to be travel-related.

Comment: OK, I edited it. I am asking about carry on.

Comment: "The question is travel related: I am wondering about this for carry on." - it wasn't closed as off-topic, it just generated 3 clarifying questions in comments within minutes, and therefore was clearly not clearly defined enough yet ;) Tags and verbosity help!

Comment: I don't think it's that bad a question, given carry on restrictions

Comment: My observation:  I've worn a belt pack without question, I've worn a Scottevest (lots of pockets but designed more subtly than pocket vests are) without question.  Things which you can wear while in your seat don't seem to cause notice--which makes sense as they aren't going to take up any cargo space.

Comment: what about a [Rufus Roos](http://www.skyscanner.net/news/rufus-roo-luggage-waistcoat-review) and other "wearable luggage" solutions

Comment: "The Roo material is quite thin and we wonder how this would stand up to  prolonged or rough use." -- that's why I am looking at sturdier clothing for a similar purpose. I have a Scottevest jacket and the pockets are definitely not load bearing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely answer is: **whatever the check-in employees think**. For example there's a [well-known video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEMS8CMfJ_g) by [Jaktogo.com](http://www.jaktogo.com/) where a man succesfully transforms a bag into a 'coat', allowing him to bring it on-board (on Ryanair!):

[image: ryanair bag coat]

If you can convince the airline employees that your 'bag' is a 'vest', you're good to go. If you can't, you'll have to pay extra or check it in as a bag.